# "invalid hexadecimal representation" for spring mongo data repository interface

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a repository interface as follows:

```
public interface ExcursionAttendeeRepository extends MongoRepository<ExcursionAttendee, String> {

    ExcursionAttendee findByWorkflowItemId(String workflowItemId);

    @Query("{ 'excursionEvent._id' : { '$oid' : ?0 } }")
    List<ExcursionAttendee> findByExcursionId(String excursionId);

    @Query("{ 'student._id' : {'$oid' : ?0} , 'excursionEvent._id' : { '$oid' : ?1 } }")
    ExcursionAttendee findByStudentIdAndEventId(String studentId, String excursionId);

    @Query("{ 'student._id' : { '$oid' : ?0 } }")
    List<ExcursionAttendee> findByStudentId(String studentId);
}
```

While Bean creation spring throws following exception.

```
Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0.1':
  Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5172829b' of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter] while setting bean property 'messageListener';
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5172829b':
    Cannot resolve reference to bean 'productDetailsEventConsumer' while setting bean property 'delegate';
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productDetailsEventConsumer': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cinglevue.veip.service.excursion.ExcursionAttendeeService com.cinglevue.veip.service.erp.impl.ProductDetailsEventConsumer.excursionAttendeeService;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'excursionAttendeeServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cinglevue.veip.repository.excursion.ExcursionAttendeeRepository com.cinglevue.veip.service.excursion.impl.ExcursionAttendeeServiceImpl.excursionAttendeeRepository;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'excursionAttendeeRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId: [_param_0]
```

Ideally this exceptions should get thrown when trying to initialise a `ObjectId` with an invalid string. [ [code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/bson/src/main/org/bson/types/ObjectId.java) ]. I'm wondering how the class gets initialised in order for an exception to get thrown while bean creation. Any tips on this?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same question and following should work.

```
@Query("{ 'student' : { '$id': ?0 } }")
List<ExcursionAttendee> findByStudentId(String studentId);
```

If it is a DBRef it should be like this, (This is what im using after the same issue, I have a DBRef in my case)

```
@Query("{ 'student': {'$ref': 'user', '$id': ?0} }")
List<ExcursionAttendee> findByStudentId(String studentId);
```

For DBRef this should work as well,

```
List<ExcursionAttendee> findByStudentId(String studentId);
```

I found the answer from [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1070).

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Query("{ 'student._id' : {'$oid' : ?0} , 'excursionEvent._id' : { '$oid' : ?1 } }")
ExcursionAttendee findByStudentIdAndEventId(String studentId, String excursionId);
```

You don't need to specify @Query if you follow [spring-data method naming conventions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.9.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details).

Answer (score 0):

The query should work with

```
@Query("{ 'student._id' : ?0} , 'excursionEvent._id' : ?1 } }")
```

Reference: https://jira.spring.io/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/DATAMONGO-1070/DATAMONGO-1070.html